# "Link" from "react-router-dom" inside "extra" in antd card not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a content component like this:

```js
<Content style={{ maxWidth: "99%" }}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/home">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/products/:id">
          <p>apsokfopaskdfop</p>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/products">
          <ProductList />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Content>
```

My ProductList

```js
export const ProductList = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  return (
     {items && (
          items.map(item => {
            return <ProductCard
              id={item.id}
              name={item.name}/>
          })
)}
```

and I have a ProductCard like this:

```js
export const ProductCard = ({ id, name }) => {
  return (
        <Card
          title={name}
          hoverable
          extra={<Link to={`/products/${id}`} >More information</Link>}
          style={{ height: 240 }}
        />
)}
```

And the `Link` inside the `extra` property isn't working. When I click on the `More information` the path changes so my url changes to `http://localhost:3000/products/1` but the content stays the same, the `p` tag inside my `switch` doesn't appears on the screen neither if I try to change to `<Link to="/home" />`. But if I reload my page with `F5` the content changes. Any help?

EDIT:

**App.jsx**

```js
return (
      <Router>
         <MenuComponent />
         <ContentComponent />
         <Footer />
      </Router>
)}
```

**ContentComponent.jsx**

```js
export const ContentComponent = () => {
return (

   <Content style={{ maxWidth: "99%" }}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/home">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/products/:id">
          <p>apsokfopaskdfop</p>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/products">
          <ProductList />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Content>
)}
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include your entire routing setup so we can see from app root/router to the `ProductCard` component with `Link`?

Comment: @DrewReese I edited the question, is this enough?

Comment: Sure, just wanted to see if it was something simple like rendering more than one `Router` in the ReactTree. I don't see any overt issue here, think you can create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and live debug in?

Comment: I'll do that, just a sec

Comment: @DrewReese here it is [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-mountain-4c0q1?file=/src/components/ProductCard.jsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found your issue, its to do with your `context.jsx` file. Only found it from your code sandbox so thanks for including that.

You are using BrowerRouter which is meant to be for the Router (which you are using). Routes is a seperate component.

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
```

but its should be

```js
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
```

Comment: Yeah, that was it, copy and paste the imports rsrs... My bad, ty for the answer

Comment: Only found it when I saw your sandbox so thanks for including that

Comment: @OtávioKochi So there was another router component 

Comment: Just one question, why the other routes was working? I had an menu with some `Link`s to other components and the router was working fine, just to this particular case it wasn't any idea?

Comment: Where they all nested in the same Switch?

Comment: @RichardHpa yes they were, all inside my `ContentComponent` just like in my answer above, but there was 5 more routes